# SDL_rect does not name a type

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've been trying out SDL 2, and am getting a `SDL_Rect does not name a type` error...
The code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;


SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gWSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface* gFinalImage = NULL;
int screenW = 640;
int screenH = 480;

SDL_Rect stretchRect;
stretchRect.x = stretchRect.y = 0;
stretchRect.w = screenW;
stretchRect.h = screenH;
```

The error log :

```
||=== Build: Debug in SDLEvents (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
D:\My Works\SDL Stretching\TestingSDL.cpp|12|error: 'stretchRect' does not name a type|
D:\My Works\SDL Stretching\TestingSDL.cpp|13|error: 'stretchRect' does not name a type|
D:\My Works\SDL Stretching\TestingSDL.cpp|14|error: 'stretchRect' does not name a type|
```

I've checked online and on another question here but haven't been able to solve the problem so far....
Thanks guys

Comment: The error in your title and description doesn't match the actual error you're getting... And this is really really basic. Code goes in functions, not at top-level like that. Please recheck your favorite book/tutorial on C++.

Comment: I admit I did a stupid mistake, which I have now been made aware of. However, I would like to say that my title is the very error the compiler gives me, and in that way, I believe my question is right.
Thank you for correcting me though :)

Comment: Your title "SDL_rect does not name a type", your compiler error "'stretchRect' does not name a type". How are those the same?

Comment: stretchRect is of the type SDL_Rect. It would be stupid to use stretchRect since readers wouldn't know what the variable is.

Comment: No. "SDL_Rect does not name a type", if that was the actual error you were having, implies a problem with includes. "<somevar> does not name a type" implies a syntax problem. Thus your title is completely misleading and misrepresents your question.

Comment: Well, alright... 
Thank you for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the code you show correctly, you try to do initialization of the rectangle in the global scope, outside of any functions. That's not possible the way you do it, you can't have assignment statements outside of functions.

There are two solutions:

1. Initialize in declaration, like

   ```
   SDL_Rect stretchRect = { values... };
   ```
2. Declare variable in the global scope, and initialize in function:

   ```
   SDL_Rect stretchRect;

   ...

   int main()
   {
       stretchRect.x = stretchRect.y = 0;
       stretchRect.w = screenW;
       stretchRect.h = screenH;

       ...
   ```